# innerHTML is not hiding in javascript validation

Tags: javascript

```
function editvalidation() {

    var isDataValid = true;

    var currentCourseO = document.getElementById("currentCourseNo");
    var newCourseNoO = document.getElementById("newCourseNo");

    var currentCourseMsgO = document.getElementById("currentAlert");
    var newCourseMsgO = document.getElementById("newAlert");


    if (currentCourseO.value == "") {
        currentCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Course to edit from the Course Drop Down Menu";
        newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        isDataValid = false; 
    } else {
        currentCourseMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    }


    if (newCourseNoO.value == "") {
        newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please fill in the Course ID in your Edit";
        isDataValid = false;
    } else {
        newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    }


    return isDataValid;

}
```

Hi, in the code above what I am trying to do is that if the `currentCourseO.value == ""` is met, then display its string message but do not display the string message for `newCourseMsgO`.

If `currentCourseO.value == ""` is not met then display the string for `newCourseMsgO` which is `newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please fill in the Course ID in your Edit";` if this validation is met.

At the moment it is not hiding the string for `newCourseMsgO` when `currentCourseO.value == ""` is met. Can I please have answer in javascript please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your two if-else statements should be connected, right now they are not dependent on one another. Try this:

```
if (currentCourseO.value == "") {
    currentCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Course to edit from the Course Drop Down Menu";
    newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "";
    isDataValid = false; 
} else {
    if (newCourseNoO.value == "") {
        newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = "Please fill in the Course ID in your Edit";
        isDataValid = false;
    } else{
        newCourseMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
    }
}
```